# How do I configure custom URL handlers on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, url, protocol

I've been reading a lot online about custom URL handlers / custom protocol handlers such as:

- [Launching External Applications using Custom Protocols under OSX](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/127152-launching-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-under-osx)
- [OS X URL handler to open links to local files](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001154.html)

I get that you can tell the system that a particular program is able to handle a certain scheme / protocol with the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Local File</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>local</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>NSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

But if there are multiple applications that are capable of opening the same URL handler, such as `mailto:` how do you specify which one you want the system to use?

There were some references to utilities like the `More Internet preference pane` which no longer seems to be available from the author's site. I did find it online by Googling but it seems a bit shaky - like it was written for an older OSX - perhaps Tiger.

I haven't been able to find information on how to set the URL handler for protocols and custom protocols. I'm assuming there is a `plist` file somewhere that I can edit - or maybe there is a newer, better utility that works well with Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The file you seek is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`.

It holds an array called `LSHandlers`, and the Dictionary children that define an `LSHandlerURLScheme` can be modified accordingly with the `LSHandlerRole`. You need to [convert this binary file][1] to edit it.

Rather than manually editing this file, you can use [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps). Note that this app is a successor to RCDefaultApp, which has been unmaintained, but it also appears to have some bugs.

Comment: 4 minutes 19 seconds? Seriously?

Comment: Thanks for the fast and detailed answer. Looks good! Question though - I think that I tried RCDefaultApp before and had some issue with it. Has it been working seamlessly for you?

Comment: @cwd I honestly have to say I don't use it often. More for screenshots for Super User than anything else :) Whenever I need to change file associations I do it through the *Get Info…* dialog in Finder. I never needed to change protocol and MIME handlers. But it seemed stable enough for me.

Comment: This seems to be to open a real "app". What if I want to do some custom processing, using a terminal command, etc?

Comment: @nute Just from the top of my head, not sure. Perhaps an app created with Automator that wraps a shell script?

Comment: How can I receive input in the automator? Like, the content of the URL?

Comment: I found my answer using AppleScript (https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/127152-Launching-External-Applications-using-Custom-Protocols-under-OSX)

Comment: Just a note, if you have multiple apps/app-versions handling the same protocol (e.g. IntelliJ EAP, IntelliJ), you can choose the specific one to use in the the `Apps` tab in `RCDefaultApp`. It is still working for me in macOS 10.11.

Comment: May need to revise the answer since the image 1st image is missing and the 2nd image code has been reassigned to a completely irrelevant image

Comment: @MrU Not sure what you're talking about – the post shows like this for me: http://imgur.com/a/4o7fZ

Comment: @slhck Wierd... I'm recieving a 404 image, and an image related to the Akinator.... – Looking in the post's details here are the links that I'm getting. 404 – http://i.stack.imgur.com/HVCo2.png | Akinator  – http://i.stack.imgur.com/S9xqn.png

Comment: @MrU I suppose your ISP or another entity is messing with your Internet access?

Comment: The preference pane [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) worked successfully for me on macOS 10.15.7 Catalina. I opened the preference pane, selected "URI schemes", scrolled down to the "tel" protocol handler, and changed it from Skype.app to FaceTime.app (Apple's native solution).

And from then on selecting a telephone number in Safari and then right-clicking to open a context menu shows "Call XXX using iPhone" which then uses the native call handling instead of Skype again.

Comment: ^ Anyone interested, I created a full HowTo with screenshots at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252116843

Comment: I'm getting `SwiftDefaultApps ERROR -10810: An unknown error has occurred.`. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It's frustrating how Apple makes such a simple task so hard and cumbersome.

Comment: @ssppjj No idea. Please file an issue in the repository! (The project seems a bit unmaintained …)

Answer (score 22):

*Update Jul 2017: RCDefaultApp and `lstool` no longer work on macOS 10.12 or later. We'll have to find a new solution.*

*Edit Mar 2018*
I found [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) but can't test as I'm not on High Sierra yet.

---

Furthering the previous answer, if you would like to do this on the command line you can use the `lstool` command, which is the core of RCDefaultApp, found under `RCDefaultApp.prefPane/Contents/Resources/lstool`.

Its usage is straightforward:

```
[~]$lstool --help
Usage:

lstool read [<lsscheme> [<type>]]
lstool [-n] write <lsscheme> <type> <app>
lstool [-n] setoption <lsscheme> <type> login|ignorecreator YES|NO
lstool [-n] register {<app>}
lstool [-n] unregister {<path> | <app>}
lstool apps

-n means do not make changes
<lsscheme> is one of: internet, media, url, extension, uti, mime, ostype
<app> is the path to an application or a name to be looked up
```

Comment: I found a possible replacement for RCDefaultApp at https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps although you will have to build it yourself with Xcode.

Comment: I'm using version 2.1 of RCDefaultApp and it works just fine for me on 10.12. At least is still lists all items. Or does only some specific operation not work any more? Please elaborate

Comment: @SuperTempel The `lstool` command-line tool displays this error when you try to run it: `objc[1049]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.` (`lstool` is the internal program used by the RCDefaultApp preference pane. While the preference pane appears to work, I don't think it can do anything because `lstool` is broken.)

Comment: SwiftDefaultApps [apparently doesn't work](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/issues/3) on Intel processors. No fix until at least April 2018.

Comment: I am the developer of SwiftDefaultApps, SWDA was coded from the beginning with macOS Sierra and higher in mind (In fact, I began working on it after much frustration reading this question and similar ones). It was not working in 10.13 largely due to a bug in either Swift or macOS itself, but it appears to have been fixed with the update to 10.13.4/Swift 4.1.

Comment: I tried running `lstool` in macOS 10.13, and I got: `objc[14334]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.`.

Answer (score 22):

Listing current LaunchServices URL handler settings on Apple OS X 10.10 (Yosemite):

```
defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure
```

Comment: Yay for using the builtin tools that don't break or require you to go download something.

Comment: This doesn't list all defaults for every protocol though, only some.

Answer (score 9):

Open the file with XCode works quite easy.

Using the build in command `plutil` as described in the answer on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5815759 to convert between format xml1 or binary1 works similar.

```
plutil -convert xml1 /file-i-wish

nano /file-i-wish & save file 

plutil -convert binary1 /file-i-wish
```

No need for 'alien' tools :-)

Answer (score 5):

I actually wrote an application simplifying registration of custom URL protocols, if anyone is interested. It is called LinCastor (https://onflapp.github.io/blog/pages/LinCastor.html).
Handlers can be defined as AppleScript or shell script (which can perl, python or what ever).

Comment: Very nice idea, but I’m afraid I can’t get the supplied example script to work.   More on your blog, awaiting moderation: https://getitdoneapps.wordpress.com/lincastor-browser/support/comment-page-1/#comment-9

Comment: That seemed to be some baffling line-break weirdness in the example file, diagnosed by running the script from the command line.  (“/bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted”)  Saving a copy in BBEdit, and changing and recharging the line breaks to/from Windows, worked around the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti):

```
echo $'com.apple.mail mailto\ncom.googlecode.iterm2 x-man-page'>~/.duti;duti ~/.duti
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to list current LaunchServices URL handler settings with Xcode on Apple OS X 10.10+ (Yosemite):

```
open -a Xcode ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist
```

Answer (score -1):

I just tried the old More Internet, under El Capitan.

It is funky and the only way it works is via using the up and down arrow keys to select the protocol, and a drag/drop of the APP icon into the window to make a change.

I switched the default from Safari to Chrome, and the change stuck, so it works still.

Comment: What is this? Your answer is unclear.