# Go to network folder with an HTML anchor on a Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

To accomplish the task of opening a CIFS/Samba folder from a browser you can make a `.URL` "internet shortcut" file that Windows downloads and opens. On linux, xdg-open will handle `smb://` anchor links. Is there a way to accomplish the same task on a Mac?

On Windows

```
<a href="http://a.co/file.url">This is a link.</a>
<!-- contents of file.url:
[InternetShortcut]
URL="file:////10.0.1.202/myShare/my Folder"
-->
```

On Linux:

```
<a href="smb://10.0.1.202/myShare/my Folder">This link works on glorious Linux</a>
<!-- the protocol gets handled by xdg-open -->
```

On MacOS?

```
<a href="[???]">A link that works on the BSD based MacOS.</a>
```

Comment: I've found a doc on Alias files, which are binary and I've found no documentation on how to make one programatically in any language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)#File_structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a SMB server to test any of this, but Safari accepts this in a .html file:

```
<a href="smb://10.0.1.202/myShare/myFolder">This link works with Safari</a>
<!-- the protocol gets handled by NetAuthSysAgent -->
```

For Firefox, assign Finder to handle the smb content type.

Finder will open a Drag Clipping file, e.g., myFolder.inetloc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>URL</key>
   <string>smb://10.0.1.202/myShare/myFolder</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: That works on Safari, but not chrome... Will look into whats going on.

Comment: @Ray Can you add a protocol handler to Chrome to use Finder or NetAuthSysAgent for smb?

Comment: FIXED IT! The issue was that my URL had spaces in it. Which is not a problem on Chrome+Linux, or Safari, but becomes a problem on Chrome+Mac! P.S. I can customize what happens with:  http://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x