# Set sip/tel URL/LSHandler back to OS X Mac Continuity/Wifi Calling instead of Skype

Tags: macos, skype, file-association, sip, plist

I recently installed skype for business and it hijacked my Mac's ability to make calls via my iPhone (Continuity) or Wifi Calling.  I wanted to know how to set it back, but I figured it out before i posted this question.  So answer is below.  [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following plist [(Source)](https://superuser.com/a/548122/398204) needs to be edited.  I suggest 'duplicating' the file first, so you will have a backup if needed.

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist
```

If you have Xcode, you can just open/edit the plist directly (not in the scope of this answer), but if not, it needs to be converted from  binary to XML format since textedit can't open it as-is.

To convert it into XML, use the following command [(Source)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101720/101663) in terminal.

```
plutil -convert xml1 /Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist
```

Open the file and then search (CMD+F) for `skype` or `<string>tel</string>`

Either delete the following structure, or edit it, by commenting it out using `<--!` and `-->` at the top and bottom of the `<dict>` [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320953)

Before:

```
<dict>
    <key>LSHandlerPreferredVersions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
        <string>-</string>
    </dict>
    <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
    <string>com.microsoft.skypeforbusiness</string>
    <key>LSHandlerURLScheme</key>
    <string>tel</string>
</dict>
```

After:

```
<!--
<dict>
    <key>LSHandlerPreferredVersions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
        <string>-</string>
    </dict>
    <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
    <string>com.microsoft.skypeforbusiness</string>
    <key>LSHandlerURLScheme</key>
    <string>tel</string>
</dict>
-->
```

Save the file and reboot.