# Google Chrome not launching Mac terminal for handling SSH protocol

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, mac, terminal, shell

Mac OS: 10.14.6 Mojave
Google Chrome Version: 83.0

I had installed Secure Shell App in Google Chrome. Before that clicking on SSH links(ssh://@) would auto-launch the terminal. After installing Secure Shell App the SSH links were being opened by the Secure Shell app in a new tab.

Due to some reasons I needed to go back to auto-launching the terminal for all SSH links. So I removed Secure Shell from Chrome.

After this when I clicked on SSH links it would redirect to something like below:

chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html#user@host:22

Tried removing Chrome from Applications. Cleared out the ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/. Then did a clean reinstall but still no luck.

Would really appreciate any help to resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

t turns out the issue isn’t directly related to Chrome. It’s Mac OS settings to launch preferred App to handle a protocol or task.

Resolution:
https://superuser.com/a/548122

You can easily install the required tool(SwiftDefaultApps) to modify the preferences file  /Users//Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist

Command to install SwiftDefaultApps [from terminal]: brew cask install swiftdefaultappsprefpane [homebrew needs to be installed already]

Alternative download: https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/releases

You can also clone and compile the source code using Xcode from github:
https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps

After installing navigate to /Users//Library/PreferencePanes/SwiftDefaultApps.prefPane using Finder. Double click on the file to launch. If it doesn’t launch then go to System Preferences in Mac OS--> Security and Privacy to allow it.

Root Cause: A browser extension can sometimes change the default preferences entries in com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist and it’ll not be reverted back even when the extension is removed.